# unreachable variable assigned in switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have the following code.  A switch statement that takes in a state name and sets another variable to the abbriviation of that state.  However, after I close my switch statement I get an error saying the variable is unreachable.

```
string stateab;

switch (s)
{
    case "Alabama":
        stateab = "AL";
        break;
    case "Alaska":
        stateab = "AK";
        break;
    case "Arizona":
        stateab = "AZ";
        break;
    case "Arkansas":
        stateab = "AR";
        break;
    case "California":
        stateab = "CA";
        break;
    case "Colorado":
        stateab = "CO";
        break;
    case "Connecticut":
        stateab = "CT";
        break;
    case "Delaware":
        stateab = "DE";
        break;
    case "DENIED":
        stateab = "DENIED";
        break;
    case "District of Columbia":
        stateab = "DC";
        break;
    case "Florida":
        stateab = "FL";
        break;
    case "Georgia":
        stateab = "GA";
        break;
    case "Hawaii":
        stateab = "HI";
        break;
    case "Idaho":
        stateab = "ID";
        break;
    case "Illinois":
        stateab = "IL";
        break;
    case "Indiana":
        stateab = "IN";
        break;
    case "Iowa":
        stateab = "IA";
        break;
    case "Kansas":
        stateab = "KS";
        break;
    case "Kentucky":
        stateab = "KY";
        break;
    case "Louisiana":
        stateab = "LA";
        break;
    case "Maine":
        stateab = "ME";
        break;
    case "Maryland":
        stateab = "MD";
        break;
    case "Massachusetts":
        stateab = "MA";
        break;
    case "Michigan":
        stateab = "MI";
        break;
    case "Minnesota":
        stateab = "MN";
        break;
    case "Mississippi":
        stateab = "MS";
        break;
    case "Missouri":
        stateab = "MO";
        break;
    case "Montana":
        stateab = "MT";
        break;
    case "Nebraska":
        stateab = "NE";
        break;
    case "Nevada":
        stateab = "NV";
        break;
    case "New Hampshire":
        stateab = "NH";
        break;
    case "New Jersey":
        stateab = "NJ";
        break;
    case "New York":
        stateab = "NY";
        break;
    case "North Carolina":
        stateab = "NC";
        break;
    case "North Dakota":
        stateab = "ND";
        break;
    case "Ohio":
        stateab = "OH";
        break;
    case "Oklahoma":
        stateab = "OK";
        break;
    case "Oregon":
        stateab = "OR";
        break;
    case "Pennsylvania":
        stateab = "PA";
        break;
    case "Rhode Island":
        stateab = "RI";
        break;
    case "South Carolina":
        stateab = "SC";
        break;
    case "South Dakota":
        stateab = "SD";
        break;
    case "Tennessee":
        stateab = "TN";
        break;
    case "Texas":
        stateab = "TX";
        break;
    case "Utah":
        stateab = "UT";
        break;
    case "Vermont":
        stateab = "VT";
        break;
    case "Virginia":
        stateab = "VA";
        break;
    case "Washington":
        stateab = "WA";
        break;
    case "West Virginia":
        stateab = "WV";
        break;
    case "Wisconsin":
        stateab = "WI";
        break;
    case "Wyoming":
        stateab = "WY";
        break;

}

Console.WriteLine(stateab);
```

The last line gives me an error stating the variable does not exist in the current context.  Any ideas?

Comment: is this your full code? what happen when you set `string stateab = string,empty;`?

Comment: This code cries for help from a Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: Agree with @Steve or an enum decorated with a description attribute. Either way not this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `break;` and not continue at the end of each case..

Answer (score 7):

The compiler requires you to ensure that the `stateab` variable is assigned some value before it may be read. In your case, you need to cater for situations where none of the `case` clauses are met by the `s` value (even if this is not possible by your application’s logic).

You may work around it trivially either by initializing your `stateab` variable with an initial value:

```
string stateab = "";
```

… or by including a `default` clause in your `switch` statement:

```
case "Wyoming":
    stateab = "WY";
    break;
default:
    stateab = "Unknown";
    break;
```

Comment: The OP amended the code shortly after posting it. I assumed that the error message was not updated.

Comment: Ah, sorry, he did that during the grace period so I cannot see it. Please disregard my comment, then :)

Comment: No problem :-) [YavgenyP’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10962893/1149773) was posted before the update and addressed the original issue. (The OP used `continue;`, rather than `break;`, at the end of each `case` block.)

Answer (score 0):

C# requires **default** case when using switch statement. It will not compile without it. Worth try a default case in the end.

```
default:
   //do something
   break;
```

Comment: Where ever did you get the idea that a `default` case label is *required*!?

Comment: Not required; the problem here is lack of definite assignment of `stateab`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the format for the `switch` statement:

```
switch (expression) {    
      case constant-expression: statement
      jump-statement  
      [default:statement
      jump-statement] 
}
```

You should include a `default` case and use `break` at the end of each case.

Answer (score 0):

You have a compiler error, because local variable could stay uninitialized, if you pass to your `switch` statement some string, which will not be listed in cases (e.g. `"Hello world"`). So, you should initialize your local variable before first time you use it. You can do it at declaration point before `switch` statement:

```
string stateab = "";
```

Or you can add `default` case to your `switch` where you rise an exception (or provide default value to abbreviate).

```
switch (s)
{
    case "Alabama":
         stateab = "AL";
         break;
    // ...
    default:
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRange("s");
}
```

.